# Writing C function to determine probability of 0 or 1 occurrence from a Data Array

Tags: c

I have a set of data provided through rows and columns with one column representing 1 or 0 for any number of rows.  The Data set is stored in a .text file

I would like to know how to write a function to determine the probability of true and false occurring.

This would be done in C.

Below is an example of the Data Set where the last column determines 0 or 1:

```
-1,0.78,1,1,0,1,0.6,-1,0.38,0
-1,0.78,1,0,1,0,1,-1,0.25,0
-1,0.56,1,0,1,0,1,-1,0.63,0
-1,0.67,0,0,1,0,0.6,0,0.5,1
-1,0.69,1,0,0,0,1,-1,0.31,0
-1,0.53,1,1,1,0,0.8,1,0.5,0
```

Comment: What does "for each count of variable" mean? Do you mean "any number of rows"?

Comment: Traverse the array, count "trues", count "falses" and calculate the true/false ratio according to the total number of elements.

Comment: Am I missing something or do you just want to know how to get to 0.4 for your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
int nbtrues = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < NBOFROWS; i++)
{
  if (row[i] == true)
    nbtrues++;    
}

double probability = (double)nbtrues / NBOFWORDS;
```

We can't tell you much more as you didn't show under which form your data is stored. Is your data set in a text file?

Comment: Yes it is in a text file

Comment: Then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69675016/edit)  and put all relevant information __info the question__. Hint: you need `fopen`, and `fscanf`.